# Identify multiple href redirections to a word

Tags: php

I wrote this code for a translation [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNtc2.png) which I use inside my dictionary website.

```html
<div class="row">
    <?php
     $stmt_word1 = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM word_language_meanings WHERE word_id = '".$word_id."'");
     $stmt_word1->execute();
     $wordLangRows=$stmt_word1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     
     $counter = 1;
     foreach($wordLangRows as $k => $v)
     {
      if($v['word_language'] != $language)
      {
    ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4 black_color" id="col-sm-4-translations">
     <h5><strong><?php echo $v['word_language']; ?></strong></h5>
     <span class="<?php if($v['word_language'] == 'Старобългарски') { echo 'bulgarian_font'; } ?>"><a style="color: gray;" href="dictionary.php?meaning=<?php echo $v['word_meaning']; ?>&language=<?php echo $word_language; ?>"><?php echo $v['word_meaning']; ?></a></span>
       </div>
    <?php
      }
     }
    ?>
   </div>
```

Unfortunately the code below does not redirect me to the particular word I'd choose from the translation table.

```html
<span class="<?php if($v['word_language'] == 'Старобългарски') { echo 'bulgarian_font'; } ?>"><a style="color: gray;" href="dictionary.php?meaning=<?php echo $v['word_meaning']; ?>&language=<?php echo $word_language; ?>"><?php echo $v['word_meaning']; ?></a></span>
```

It shows me [this url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4A6x.png) but as u can see the language is not defined. What I am trying to do is to tell, if the word is for example "test" and its an english translation, to redirect me to that word of that particular language, as it's set in the database. Has anyone any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$word_language` is not define. Use `$v['word_language']` instead

```
<span class="<?php if($v['word_language'] == 'Старобългарски') { echo 'bulgarian_font'; } ?>"><a style="color: gray;" href="dictionary.php?meaning=<?php echo $v['word_meaning']; ?>&language=<?php echo $v['word_language'] ?>"><?php echo $v['word_meaning']; ?></a></span>
```

Comment: It works, but it seems to me that when I click on the word, am then redirected to the words list of that particular language, the word is not getting recognized. And one last thing, will this code work if it is for example test, trial. Can this code seperate this two words by the comma I'd insert betwen them?

Comment: can you help me out with the questions above?